# MouseListener and JPanel Objects

Tags: static, calendar, jpanel, mouselistener, non-static

So, I am working on building a calendar. My aim is to make it possible for the user to click on the screen so as to scroll through different months of the year. In main, I created 42 objects of a class named "DateSquare" (which are the different individual dates of a given time period) and added them to a JPanel object. My main problem is that I am unable to substitute or remove these DateSquare objects and replace them with other DateSquare objects because I cannot pass the objects (which are non-static) as actual parameters to my function which would clear the JPanel of the old 42 DateSquare objects and add the following 42 DateSquare objects. My last attempt was passing the JPanel which contains the 42 objects (or dates, if you will) as an actual parameter to this function that would clear it of its objects and put in the new ones (this function is called "setDates"). However, Eclipse tells me that this JPanel called "dates" cannot be resolved to a field. 
Any ideas as to how to solve this problem will be greatly appreciated!!!
Some code:

```
public class DateSquareTester {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
           JFrame window = new JFrame("DateSquareTester");
           JPanel content = new JPanel();
           MouseHandler listener = new MouseHandler();

           content.addMouseListener(listener);

           JPanel dates = new JPanel();
           dates.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

           JPanel transferDates = new JPanel();
           transferDates.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
           content.add(dates);
           dates.add(transferDates);
      }

      public static JPanel setDates(JPanel dates, MouseEvent evt, 
               DateStatus[] dateArray, int referencePosition){  
             // function that returns a JPanel with 42 DateSquare        
             // objects and clears the previous 42 DateSquare objects!  

       JPanel newDates = new JPanel();
       newDates.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
       dates.removeAll();
       ...
       dates.add(newDates);
       return dates;            
     }

 //this MouseHandler class is NOT nested
 public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener {

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){   
        DateSquareTester.dates.add(
        DateSquareTester.setDates(DateSquareTester.dates, evt,    
        DateSquareTester.dateArray, DateSquareTester.referencePosition));
        //THE COMPILER DOES NOT RECOGNIZE"DateSquareTester.dates"!!        

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Dates is local to main method. It is not visible in MouseHandler scope, you can define a constructor at MouseHandler to pass the Dates reference.

Comment: I am extremely new at Java, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I know how to declare constructors, just unsure as to whether I should include Dates in the formal parameters or in the { ...} part of the constructor.

Comment: You also can define three setter methods to pass dates, datearray and referencePosition to the MouseHandler

Answer (score 1):

MouseHandler is causing trouble because it's trying to access a variable that's out of its scope.

Instead of replacing the old panels with new ones, it may be a better idea to simply change the contents of the existing panels:

```
/* Calendar.java */
public class CalendarPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int WIDTH = 6;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 7;

    private final DatePanel[] datePanels;

    /* I've used a enumeration here but an integer variable would work. */
    private Month currentMonth = Month.JANUARY;

    public CalendarPanel() {

        super(new GridLayout(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        datePanels = new DatePanel[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
        for (int i = 0; i < datePanels.length; i++) {
                datePanels[i] = new DatePanel(i);
            add(datePanels[i]);
        }
        updateDatePanels();

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                    currentMonth = Month.FEBRUARY;
                updateDatePanels();
            }

            ...
        });
    }

    private void updateDatePanels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < datePanels.length; i++) {
            datePanels[i].setDayNumber(currentMonth.ordinal() + i);
        }
    }
}

/* DatePanel.java */
public class DatePanel extends JPanel {

    private int dayNumber;

    public DatePanel(int dayNumber) {
        super();
        this.dayNumber = dayNumber;
        setSize(20, 20);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setDayNumber(int dayNumber) {
        this.dayNumber = dayNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(dayNumber), 20, 20);
        repaint();
    }
}
```